# Normalised subgroup and $O_{2'}(G)$ and $O^{2'}(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Denote by $N = O^{2'}(G)$ the smallest normal subgroup, such that $G / N$ has odd order. Let $H$ a subgroup of odd order which is normalised by every Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is normalised by $N$ and further $H \cap N \unlhd N$, so that $H \cap N \le O_{2'}(N)$, where $O_{2'}(N)$ denotes the largest normal subgroup of $N$ of odd order.

Also if $O_{2'}(G) = 1$, then $O_{2'}(N) = 1$.

My questions:

1) Why does $H \cap N \le O_{2'}(N)$ holds?

2) How to proof that if $H$ is normalised by every Sylow-$2$-subgroup, then it is normalised by $N$?

3) Why does $O_{2'}(G) = 1$ implies $O_{2'}(N) = 1$?

Comment: Probably a typo: let $G=H=N$ be a 2-group to get a counterexample to (1). Perhaps $H$ is assumed to have odd order?

Comment: For (2), $N$ is the subgroup generated by the Sylow 2-subgroups. If $H$ is normalized by $A$ and by $B$, then $H$ is normalized by $\langle A,B\rangle$.

Comment: For (3) $O_{2'}(N)$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: For 2, notice that $N$ must contain every Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ as $G/N$ has odd order. On the other hand, if $M$ denotes the (normal) subgroup generated by all Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G,$ then $G/M$ has odd order. Hence $N = M.$ For 3:  If $X \lhd Y,$ then notice that $O_{2^{\prime}}(X) {\rm char X} \lhd Y.$  As for 1, it is not generally true ( eg what if $H = O_{2}(G)?$). It is true if $H$ has odd order, for by my answer to 2, we see that $H \lhd HN$ so that $H \cap N \lhd HN,$ and certainly $H \cap N \lhd H.$

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Yes $H$ has odd order!